# Работа UnRAR.dll с zip

Tags: windows, archive, dll

Есть программа, работающая с архивами `.rar` через `UnRAR.dll`. Возникла необходимость перейти на `.zip` формат.
*Какие* существуют аналоги для `.zip` с похожим функционалом для более удобного перехода на него?
*Нельзя* ли заставить `UnRAR.dll` работать с `.zip`, что бы не переписывать код?

Comment: При попытке открыть zip-архив UnRAR.dll сообщает что это не rar, похоже что с zip он работать не умеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будьте так добры пишите какой язык или чем вы там пользуетесь. Будем предполагать что это C++. Для него есть замечательная [zlib](http://zlib.net/). По-моему нельзя найти такую чтобы вообще ничего не переписывать. Об этом стоило позаботиться когда начинали писать программу. В SDK кстати все по пунктам расписано. Удачи Вам ;)

Comment: Спасибо! А разве для `dll` есть разница на чем писать? А так `VBA`. `zlib` не то, что я имел ввиду, но такой вариант тоже годится.  
Под "не переписывать код" имелось ввиду, что умеет ли UnRAR.dll работать с .zip? Хотя ничего подобного я не нашел, в документации написано "для rar".

Comment: Разница в том, что в архиве с UnRAR.dll есть готовые примеры подключения библиотеки к программам на C, C#, Delphi, Free Pascal, VB и т.д. В zlib есть подключаемые файлы только для C. Если для вас это не проблема, то разницы нет никакой:)

Comment: Похоже я неточно выражаюсь. Динамически подключаемые библиотеки `DLL` могут использоватся любыми приложениями, не зависимо от того, на чем и на каком языке пишутся, вас я понял, спасибо;)  
Программа досталась "в наследство" и написана на `VBA`, думаю подобных нормальных библиотек на `VBA` нету, нужно искать готовый `dll`.